# Deleting item in ForEach loop causes fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swiftui

I have a ScrollView which displays a list of rows using a ForEach loop from an array. When I delete an item from the array, I get the error: Index out of range.

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(viewModel.tasks.indices, id: \.self){ index in
        TaskRow(
            task: self.$viewModel.tasks[index],
            deleteAction: {
                self.viewModel.deleteTask(task: self.viewModel.tasks[index])
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This error only started occurring when I switched to passing the index from the ForEach loop instead of the 'task' itself. I had to do this so I could use a `@Binding var task: Task` in the subview: "TaskRow"

The 'delete action' is triggered by a button in the subview.

`viewModel.deleteTask` works as follows (using a dataManager):

```
final class StackDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
    
    var dataManager: DataManagerProtocol
    
    init(dataManager: DataManagerProtocol = DataManager.shared){
        self.dataManager = dataManager
        fetchTasks()
    }
}
extension StackDetailViewModel {

    func fetchTasks() {
        tasks = dataManager.fetchTasks()
    }

    func deleteTask(task: Task) {
        dataManager.deleteTask(task: task)
        fetchTasks()
    }

}
```

Where the dataManager does this:

```
Class DataManager {

...

    private var tasks = [Task]()

...
 
    func fetchTasks() -> [Task] {
        tasks
    }

    func deleteTask(task: Task) {
        if let index = tasks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == task.id }) {
            tasks.remove(at: index)
        }
    }

}
```

I use protocols in my app but I've removed them here for simplicity.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `viewModel.deleteTask`?

Comment: @NewDev I've updated the Q. thanks

Comment: Based on what you showed, it should work. I suspect the bug is somewhere between `DataManager` and your `ViewModel`.

Comment: in general, you do not want to delete from an array while stepping through it

Comment: @NewDev From the tests i've done. The error only occurs when I change from using `ForEach(viewModel.tasks){ task in` to what I have shown above. Keeping the dataManager and ViewModel the same.

Comment: @santi.gs... I understand. It might not be in `DataManager`, but I think based on the code you showed, it should work; i.e. I can't repro your bug. I created a quick replica of what you have, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to use the array indices directly in `ForEach` as identifiers, because indices are positional and do not identify the item which they represent. This can cause redraw issues and crashes in SwiftUI.
E.g. when you use "swipe to delete" in a regular `List`, SwiftUI knows that the item at the given position has been deleted and will probably not ask again for the full list of IDs (which are indices in this incorrect case) to redraw the content. SwiftUI will simply provide the list of remaining IDs for the next redraw, which is leading to an out-of-bounds crash.

I don't mean that this is the exact case here as I was not able to reproduce your crash.

As you write yourself the problem appears when you modify the `ForEach` to use indices instead of your tasks.

Instead of

```swift
ForEach(viewModel.tasks.indices, id: \.self){ index in
```

Use

```swift
ForEach(Array(viewModel.tasks.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, task) in
```

This gives you access to the index for the `Binding` to the task needed for `TaskRow` and the task associated. Further by specifying the tasks ID as identifier for each row, SwiftUI will not rely on the positional indices anymore.

But beware: **this solution might not perform as well for very large arrays of tasks**, because the `EnumeratedSequence` (returned by `.enumerated()` on your tasks `Array`) is flattened into a new `Array`.

So if you are working with large lists of tasks, I would recommend your initial version: `ForEach(viewModel.tasks)` and eventually pay the performance penalty in the case of `deleteAction` only.